# How can i show the result of slider changed value in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show the result of slider changed value in a textbox, but i don't know how to do that. the code is :

**Js**

```
slider = widget.getByName("Slider1");
slider.addValueChangedHandler(
    function (sender, e) {
        alert(sender.getValue());
    }
)
}
```

**Html**

```
</head>
<body>
<div style="clear: both; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; "></div>
<div class="cell" style="height:100px">
  <div class="container" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="widget" style="height: 150px; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="root">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div><input type="text" id="ValueBox" value="0"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script**

```
slider = widget.getByName("Slider1");
    slider.addValueChangedHandler(
                    function (sender, e) {
                        document.getElementById("ValueBox").value=sender.getValue();
                    }
                )           
            }

        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 </head>
    <body>
    <div style="clear: both; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; "></div>
    <div class="cell" style="height:100px">
            <div class="container" style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="widget" style="height: 150px; margin-bottom: 0px;" id="root">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    <div><input type="text" id="ValueBox" value="0"/></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```